QT QML Listview issue with QInvokable model
I have a problem with a listview element and the supply with a c++ AbstractListModel.
If I pass the listmodel via qproperty the list entries are displayed correctly.
If I pass the listmodel via qinvokable, the list is only displayed the first time the page is called up. If I call up the page a second time (regardless of whether with the same or a different listmodel), the list remains empty.
ColumnLayout { anchors.fill: parent;
        ListView { id: listview; Layout.fillWidth: true;  Layout.fillHeight: true;
            DelegateChooser {
                id: items
                role: "r_type"
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: type1; SelectlistDelegateITL { p_height: p_listheight; p_width: list.width; p_index: index; p_column1: r_col1; p_column2: r_col2; p_isHeader: false }}
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: type2; SelectlistDelegateI2TL { p_height: p_listheight; p_width: list.width; p_index: index; p_column1: r_col1; p_column2: r_col2; p_column3: r_col3; p_isHeader: false }}
            }   
            //model: cp_screen.selectlistModelA
            model: cp_screen.getSelectlistModelB()
            //currentIndex: cp_screen.getSelectlistIndex(p_key)
            currentIndex: 0
            header: SelectlistDelegateI2TL { p_height: p_listheight; p_width: list.width; p_index: -1; p_column1: cp_screen.getListHeaderIcon(p_key); p_column2: cp_screen.getListHeaderText(p_key); p_isHeader: true }
            delegate: items
            spacing: p_listspacing
        }
    }

QProperty:
Q_PROPERTY(SelectlistModel* selectlistModelA READ getSelectlistModelA NOTIFY signalSelectlistModelChanged)

SelectlistModel* getSelectlistModelA() { return m_model->selectlistModels.first(); }

QInvokable:
Q_INVOKABLE SelectlistModel* getSelectlistModelB() { return m_model->selectlistModels.first(); }

When trying via QInvokable, there is still the corresponding connection in the view for updating the model
Connections { target: cp_screen; function onSignalSelectlistModelChanged() { listview.model = cp_screen.getSelectlistModelB() } }

GetSelectListModelA and getSelectlistModelB return the identical model
Any idea what going wrong with QInvokable way?

It seems to me that the problem lies in not assigning the model but the model itself. In the former method with Q_PROPERTY, models are assigned all over again with every change, which is incorrect. The following code should probably give the same result as Q_INVOKABLE:
Q_PROPERTY(SelectlistModel* selectlistModelA READ getSelectlistModelA CONSTANT)

This way, ListView gets the model once and illustrates its info when needed. Now the question is why the data do not get updated. A specific answer requires a look into your QAbstractListModel inherited class. However, the problem usually lies in not emitting dataChanged signal. To elaborate, after the model receives new info, it should be informed to update the view:
QModelIndex topIndex = createIndex(first_row,0);
QModelIndex bottomIndex = createIndex(end_row,0);
emit dataChanged(topIndex,bottomIndex,QList<int>({roles}));

Otherwise, ListView remains with initial values. Moreover, if the change is vast and includes modification such as rowCount, one temporary and not optimized solution is to reset the whole model which should give the results same as PROPERTY notification reassign method:
beginResetModel();
endResetModel();

Though it should be avoided unless be a necessity.
